# Autopopulating program

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio, machine-learning, automation

I am working for a company and my personal project is auto populating some columns based on one column. I can't give you specifics since the information is confidential but basically, I am using description column to auto populate engine hours, model year and etc of farming equipment. For example, the description columns are usually like "John Deere 2019, it has 1500 hours. it is in good condition, it also has Hydraulics and AC. Front dual. it has enclosed cap" something like this. And I wrote almost all the codes that are needed for this on SQLite except that I faced an issue where I cannot use regex properly in the where clause (it does not produce the right results) and also the instring function in SQLite does not support specifying a range of numbers. and it can only search for a specific substring within a string. But I found out that I could solve the issue by using PATINDEX function that I could not solve by using SQLite.

So I decided to use SQL server instead and tried to find a way to automate uploading process. However, I also realized that I did not want to convert all the codes into SQL server form since it will take a long time.. I used Chat GPT and it converts a lot of stuff wrong. Also, SQL requires a little more manipulation in SQL import wizard than SQLite import function in terms of importing the csv data. I want users to be able to use the program easily. Right now, I have codes for SQLite since I solved the issue in a different way finally but I am not sure if making users to install SQLite and import and run the codes is the best way.

I thought about SSIS ETL process but I am not sure if this process is what I want. What I want is make users to easily upload the csv data and get the data based on the algorithms on which I wrote the codes for the process of autopopulating the columns based on the one column. So I looked into visual basic studio 2019. and I also used chat gpt to figure this out. The chat gpt says that I could use ASP.net to allow users to easily upload the csv file and get the columns autopopulate on a website by using and inserting the SQL codes. However, certainly, I do not know how to do this specifically. I was able to make a webpage but there are multiple pages I need to fill out to make this work in the visual studio ASP project. The chat gpt does not help the specifications since the codes are usually kinda wrong.

Do any of the data scientists or analysts have suggestions how to go about this? Also, I am pretty sure what I am doing is kinda close to machine learning since I am building an algorithms for almost every case I can think of. Are there anyways that I can teach the machine to learn how to build different cases for itself so I don't have to input new codes for new patterns when a new case rises?

Answer (score 0):

Well the fact of using Excel, ms-access, SQLite, or Oracle, or MySQL or SQL server?

All of those systems just store data in a table format. Really VERY but VERY LITTLE to do with your first issue and problem.

the simple matter, it is VERY doubt full that you can with any degree of reliability pull out the hours of of some free form text.

The simple matter is I can not imagine in ANY POSSIBLE way that the source data does not, and did not have provisions for separate entry of the machine hours.

I mean, what you going to do with this:

***My machine has 1500 hours, but only 500 hours during the winter.***

So, what you going to do with above?
There is a saying in our industry, and it was coined in the 1950's:

***History of garbage in, garbage out***
*. The first recorded use of the phrase "garbage in, garbage out" dates back to 1957. However, George Fuechsel, an IBM programmer and instructor, is generally credited with coining the term in the early 1960s. Fuechsel is said to have used the term to state concisely that a computer model or program just processes what it is given: If it is given bad information, it will produce bad information.*

So, that above statement STILL applies 100% to your issue.

The simple matter, is free form text data to try and pull out some "hours" out of a block of text is NOT going to be reliable - it just not.

So, you need to go back to the source of this data. If they can't get you data that separates out things like machine hours? Then you don't have a valid data model to work with -- END OF STORY!!!

How could it be possible that you are receiving data about some machine, yet during data entry, such information is not separated out? Even going back to punch card systems in the 1960's for management of warranty work, and work for any organization managing equipment? They don't work as you suggest.

Now, I suppose you might have some history data that you have to do a ONE time import, and attempt to parse out the hours from that text, but moving forward for any new data? Nope, not going to work, and as noted, it is NEXT TO IMPOSSIVLE to accept that at data entry point, provisions for entry of machine hours does not exist. This is NOT a possible and valid consideration here.

This means you have to go back to who is providing you such data, and as them to change the format, and produce that information from their data systems in a format you can write software against.

Once you have a working and correct concept of a data model, even a simple csv, file, then all of the rest of your desires for this task becomes trivial.

Trying to solve a mess that you been given? Nope! You find out why and how your receiving such data and if that source of data can't be changed, then you are with full knowledge simply pouring more gas on a burning barn that is a mess to start with.

You can even say use stone tablets and chisels, and the amount of hours left on a work horse back in Romain times? Such data is not just TOSSED in the middle of some free form text. They will have a ledger column, and entry for those hours. You can't run a business this way back in the stone age, or today - you just can't.

As I stated, you may have a one time data processing to try and pull out hours, but for the future and a correct define data processing system? Nope, it not going to work.

And as I stated, using SQLite, SQL server, and product x? That does not matter and is just a side show, and a wild goose chase on your part.

You need to outline the data flows here, and where and how that source data is being created is the issue here. Be it punched cards, stone tablets, or what you have now? It is NOT reasonable to assume that such data originates as free form text and you being forced to try and "pluck" out the hour value here.

fix the data source, and you fix this issue. If you can't and don't have a choice? Then you don't have a viable data processing work flow here, and all the software in the world never going to work reliable here.